# How to specify ormcofig.js in typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have `typescript`project and create following `ormconfig.js` file in project.

```
module.exports = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'db',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'db',
  entities: ['dist/entities/**/*.entity.js'],
  migrations: ['dist/migrations/develop/**/*.js'],
  logging: true,
};
```

In my project following `tsconfig.json` also created in project directory.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

after

`npm run build`

`.ts`was compiled to following directories.

```
-dist
  -migrations
    -develop
  -entities
    -entity1.js
    -entity2.js
```

Then I tried following `typeorm` `migration`

`npm run typeorm migration:create -- -n migration`

migration file is generated root directory not the specified migration directory.

`ormconfig.js` seems not to be specified .

`package.json` is following

`"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ormconfig.js"`

Where is the wrong point ?
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> migration file is generated root directory not the specified migration directory.

You can set the directory for generated migrations by adding `cli: { migrationsDir: "dist/migrations/develop" }` to your `ormconfig.js` file. 
The `migrations` property only specifies where typeorm will load migrations from.
*See [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#migrations/creating-a-new-migration)*

> ormconfig.js seems not to be specified .

I'm not sure what you mean by this, can you please elaborate?